# How to fix the issue puppeteer.use isn't a function

Tags: puppeteer

The problem that I have is that it doesn't recognize that puppeteer.use i a function. I took these lines of code `const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth') puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin()) const AdblockerPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker') puppeteer.use(AdblockerPlugin({ blockTrackers: true }))` from puppeteer extra and downloaded and followed all the instructions that I needed but it still doesn't work. The problem that I had from the beginning and which I was hoping to solve was that I can't run my programm headless: true. And sadly it didn't work entirely.

This is the error that I'm getting when I'm trying to run the program:

```
`Uncaught TypeError TypeError: puppeteer.use is not a function
at <anonymous> (undefined:3:11)
at Module._compile (undefined:1159:14)
at Module._extensions..js (undefined:1213:10)
at Module.load (undefined:1037:32)
at Module._load (undefined:878:12)
at executeUserEntryPoint (undefined:81:12)
at <anonymous> (undefined:23:47)`
```

this is my code:

```
`const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())
const AdblockerPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker')
puppeteer.use(AdblockerPlugin({ blockTrackers: true }))

const product_url = "https://www.zalando.se/nike-sportswear-air-flight-lite-mid-hoega-sneakers-          whiteblack-ni112n02z-a11.html"
const cart = "https://www.zalando.se/cart"



async function givePage(){
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true})
const page = await browser.newPage();
return page;
```

}

```
async function addToCart(page){
// going to website
await page.goto(product_url)
// clicking "handla"
await page.waitForSelector("button[class='DJxzzA u9KIT8 uEg2FS U_OhzR ZkIJC- Vn-7c- FCIprz heWLCX   JIgPn9 LyRfpJ pxpHHp Md_Vex NN8L-8 GTG2H9 MfX1a0 WCjo-q EKabf7 aX2-iv r9BRio mo6ZnF  PLvOOB']");
await page.click("button[class='DJxzzA u9KIT8 uEg2FS U_OhzR ZkIJC- Vn-7c- FCIprz heWLCX JIgPn9 LyRfpJ   pxpHHp Md_Vex NN8L-8 GTG2H9 MfX1a0 WCjo-q EKabf7 aX2-iv r9BRio mo6ZnF  PLvOOB']", elem => elem.click);
// clicking "OK" to cookies
await page.waitForSelector("button[class='uc-btn uc-btn-primary']");
await page.click("button[class='uc-btn uc-btn-primary']");
// clicking "size EU 41"
await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName('_6G4BGa _0Qm8W1 _7Cm1F9 FxZV-M IvnZ13 Pb4Ja8   ibou8b JT3_zV ZkIJC- Md_Vex JCuRr_ na6fBM _0xLoFW FCIprz pVrzNP KRmOLG NuVH8Q')[4].click());
console.log("körs")
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
// going to "cart"
await page.goto(cart)
// clicking "gå till checkout"
await page.waitForSelector("button[class='z-1-button z-coast-base-primary-accessible z-coast-  base__sticky-sumary__cart__button-checkout z-1-button--primary z-1-button--button']");
await page.click("button[class='z-1-button z-coast-base-primary-accessible z-coast-base__sticky-  sumary__cart__button-checkout z-1-button--primary z-1-button--button']", elem => elem.click);
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
// logging into gmail
const email = await page.waitForSelector("[id='login.email']");
await email.type('marc.ehadsadwa@gmail.com');
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
// typing in password
const password = await page.waitForSelector("[id='login.secret']");
await password.type('Bradasdwad');
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
// clicking "log in"
await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName('DJxzzA u9KIT8 uEg2FS U_OhzR ZkIJC- Vn-7c-    FCIprz heWLCX JIgPn9 LyRfpJ pxpHHp Md_Vex NN8L-8 GTG2H9 MfX1a0 WCjo-q EKabf7 aX2-iv r9BRio mo6ZnF E6Km4r')  [0].click());
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
// clicking "hämta hos postombud"
```

}

```
async function checkout(){
var page = await givePage();
await addToCart(page);
```

}

```
checkout();`
```

I've tried like solving the problem but when I do another one shows up like that the program don't know what  web browser it's supposed to go into.

This is my package.json:

```
package name: (marce)
version: (1.0.0)
description:
git repository:
keywords:
author:
license: (ISC)
About to write to C:\Users\marce\package.json:
```

{
"name": "marce",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"puppeteer": "^19.6.0",
"puppeteer-extra": "^3.3.4",
"puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker": "^2.13.5",
"puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.11.1"
},
"devDependencies": {},
"description": ""
}

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Answer (score 1):

Puppeteer itself does not have a use function. You'll have to use puppeteer-extra instead.

Adjust your code in the following way:

Replace:

`const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');`

With:

`const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');`

Comment: I think that it might have fixed the problem but now when I run it another one shows up Uncaught Error Error: An `executablePath` or `channel` must be specified for `puppeteer-core`
    at assert (undefined:28:15)
    at launch (undefined:92:36)
    at launch (undefined:154:105)
    at launch (undefined:128:41)

Comment: @Marcnark [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74251875/puppeteer-error-an-executablepath-or-channel-must-be-specified-for-puppete) should be the answer to your issue. 

You should try to google the error messages that you receive. That way you will find answers to your problems way faster than by asking them here.